# How to remove a GridViewDataTextColumn in devexpress gridview dynamic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

How to remove a GridViewDataTextColumn in devexpress gridview dynamic?

```
DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataTextColumn col1 = new DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataTextColumn() { FieldName = "col1", VisibleIndex = 16 };
DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataTextColumn col2 = new DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataTextColumn() { FieldName = "col2", VisibleIndex = 17 };

if (has)
{
    grd1.Columns.Add(col1);
    grd1.Columns.Add(col2);
    grd1.DataBind();
}
else if (grd1.Columns.IndexOf(grd1.Columns["col1"]) != -1 && grd1.Columns.IndexOf(grd1.Columns["col2"]) != -1)
{
    grd1.DataSource = null;
    grd1.DataBind();
    grd1.Columns.Remove(col1);
    grd1.Columns.Remove(col2);
    grd1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: what the problem ?

Comment: remove method not work @sanjayradadiya .

Comment: no one error is found in your code working well .

Comment: Error : Index out of range or less than 0? @sanjay-radadiya

Comment: This works, grd1.Columns.RemoveAt(grd1.Columns.IndexOf(grd1.Columns["col1"])); //Index 16
    grd1.Columns.RemoveAt(grd1.Columns.IndexOf(grd1.Columns["col2"])); //Index 17 > > But After visible index 18 column not work.

Comment: provide some more code to better clarify.